# Intellisense for code editor on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am developing a web based code editor using Code Mirror. This editor also supports intellisense using Control-Space keys.

I want this application to work on mobile devices too where Control-Space key combination is not available. So What would be the best approach that works both on PC as well as on mobile devices.